# how to change label content using mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, label

I try to do something easy but seems like i miss something. I try to change the content of a label when I click on a button. I do that using MVVM pattern. here is my code :

View :

```
    <Button x:Name="buttonNext" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Width="85" 
        Height="35"
        Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
        Command="{Binding Path=Next}">
        <TextBlock Text="Next"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
<Label Name="Path"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Content="{Binding path}"
       FontWeight="Bold"
       Foreground="DeepSkyBlue"
       />
```

ViewModel :

```
    public ICommand Next { get; set; } 
    private string _path;
    public string path
    {
        get
        {
            return _path;
        }
        set
        {
            _path = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("path");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            Task.Run(() => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)));
        }
    }

    public page4ViewModel(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
    {
      _path = "etape1";
       Next = new BaseCommand(GoNext);
    }

    private void GoNext(object obj)
    {
        switch (_path)
        {
            case "etape1":
                _path = "etape2";
                break;
            case : "etape2"
                _path = "etape3";
                break;
            case "etape3":
                _path = "etape4";
                break;
            default:
                _path = " ";
                break;

        }

    }
```

at first the label is "etape1" as in the constructor, but then when i click on the next button the value doesn't change. ps : the fonction to change works because i put a breakpoint to see. Thanks for your help

Comment: why do you raise your `propertychanged` async in a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the property, not the backing field.

```
private void GoNext(object obj)
{
    switch (_path)
    {
        case "etape1":
            path = "etape2"; // without underscore
            break;
        case : "etape2"
            path = "etape3";
            break;
        case "etape3":
            path = "etape4";
            break;
        default:
            path = " ";
            break;

    }
```

That will raise the notification for the change

**Edit**

It's also better using a `ViewModelBase` for your ViewModel

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

where you can define

```
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

**Alternatives**

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349365/how-to-change-label-content-using-mvvm-pattern/42349467#comment71850718_42349467) comment, we can introduce the [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx)

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Another useful variation is based on a selector, when you need to raise it for a dependent property from a *different* setter

```
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression)
    {
        if (selectorExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selectorExpression");
        MemberExpression body = selectorExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The body must be a member expression");
        RaisePropertyChanged(body.Member.Name);
    }
```

Comment: You may also want to add the [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to your RaisePropertyChanged method, so that it could be called without explicitly specifying the property name (and hence eliminating the need for verifying the property name).

Comment: @Clemens Sure, thanks. Since sometime it's also needed to call the change on a dependent Property from another setter, I prefer to add also another version with `Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression` in my `ViewModelBase`

Answer (score 2):

You need to raise the property changed event on the ui thread.

Replace

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        Task.Run(() => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)));
    }
```

with

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)));
    }
```

Also set the value for `path` not `_path`

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, Dispatcher.Invoke is not necessary in this case since it's already on the UI thread.

Just call

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Comment: Do you really need the `Dispatcher`? I'm almost positive that if you execute the "NextCommand" you are already in the UI thread...

Comment: No, you're right. It is already in the UI thread. I was just trying to say to specifically avoid using Task.Run.

Comment: Neither `Task.Run` nor `Dispatcher.Invoke` makes sense here. Instead of checking `PropertyChanged != null`, replace the whole RaisePropertyChanged method body by `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));`

Comment: @Connell.O'Dennell thx for your answer but nop, still doesn't work, is he suppose to enter in the "if" condition ? because he doesn't ....

Comment: @Json Does your ViewModel class actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or does it only declare a `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: other than with that :         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

Comment: I mean `class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }`

Comment: @Clemens nop indeed i didn't

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value in:

```
private void GoNext(object obj)
{
    switch (_path)
    {
        case "etape1":
            _path = "etape2";
            break;
        case : "etape2"
            _path = "etape3";
            break;
        case "etape3":
            _path = "etape4";
            break;
        default:
            _path = " ";
            break;

    }
```

But as You are setting `_path`, the setter in `path` is not ever called:

```
public string path
{
    set ///This is never called
    {
        _path = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("path");
    }
}
```

**Change to:**

```
switch (path)
{
    case "etape1":
        path = "etape2";
        break;
    case : "etape2"
        path = "etape3";
        break;
    case "etape3":
        path = "etape4";
        break;
    default:
        path = " ";
        break;

}
```