# C# binding received data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have got client-server app, where client gets data from server and saves it in static class:

```
 public static class DataStructure
    {
        //! Значение каждой переменной
        public static Value AxisX = new Value(@"axis_x", Dividers.AxisX);
        public static Value AxisY = new Value(@"axis_y", Dividers.AxisY);
        public static Value AxisZ = new Value(@"axis_z", Dividers.AxisZ);
        public static Value Temp = new Value(@"temp", Dividers.Temp);
        public static Value GirX = new Value(@"gir_x", Dividers.GirX);
        public static Value GirY = new Value(@"gir_y", Dividers.GirY);
        public static Value GirZ = new Value(@"gir_z", Dividers.GirZ);
        ...

        public static List<Value> ListOfValues = new List<Value>
        {
            AxisX,
            AxisY,
            AxisZ,
            Temp,
            GirX,
            GirY,
            GirZ,
            ....
        }
        ...
```

Client-side app has GUI (WPF with MVVM pattern). Client receives data from server every 1 second and they must be displayed in window.
[Screenshot (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwyXp.png)

If I want it, I must `RaisePropertyChanged()`, but I don't want to interfere in `DataSctructure` class and make properties with `RaisePropertyChanged()`. What is the best way to do it? I can create a lot of properties in ViewModel (such as `AxisX`, `AxisY`, ...) and assign them data from `ListOfValues`, but I think it is irrationally.

Or, may be, I must change structure of application?

UPDATE 1:

```
    public class Value
        {
            public Value(string name, double divider = 1.0)
            {
                Name = name;
                Divider = divider;
                HexCode = string.Empty;
                IntValue = 1;
                PhysValue = 1.0;
            }

            public readonly string Name;
            public readonly double Divider;
            public string HexCode { get; private set; }
            public int IntValue { get; private set; }
            public double PhysValue { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: how is `Value` defined?

Comment: @user1892538 I updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for instance at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349467/6996876): in this case

```
public class Value: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
          //this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
           }
        }
```

Then if Value is a class with properties (like `IntValue` and `PhysValue`, i.e. with a getter at least), you already have a collection (a list) bindable to a (read only) Control (a `DataGrid`).

for example

```
private double physValue;        
public double PhysValue { 
  get { return physValue; } 
  set {
     physValue = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Of course you have to elaborate more to implement your desired screenshot

Comment: as I understand, I must create properties in `Value` class (in `set` call `RaisePropertyChanged()`) and bind them in XAML?

Comment: Look at my answer again, there is an example

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap each `Value` in a property on your viewmodel and call `PropertyChanged` there, or you can modify the `DataStructure` class to fire `PropertyChanged`.  You will have to make `DataStructure` non static in order to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on it, however.

Speaking of which, why are you storing mutable data in a static class?  That is a very bad idea...

Comment: My first and immediately came idea was to change `DataStructure` class... It wasn't my idea to make it static...

Comment: okay. How should I do if I don't want to produce a lot of variables and save my code clean? Make instead of `List` - `ObservableList` and make event on changing collection and then bind it?

Comment: Its hard for me to say what would be better for your situation, since your code shows very little about what you are trying to do.  In fact, you mention data being updated every second, but the class you link just shows hard-coded values for each field.  Which is another thing, you should use public properties instead of public fields.